# prolog- use of multi_cumulative with multiple resources

Tags: prolog, clpfd

I need to create a schedule for tasks. I decided to use `multi_cumulative(+Tasks,+Capacities)`, which is a version of cumulative/2. These functions are from the clpfd library.

So, I have this basic example (which I have applied to a more complex program):

- Ss list, which are the start times,
- Es, the end times,
- Capacities is the list of resources with the capacities,
- List of tasks, which have the following format: start time, duration, end time,  resource consumption and task identifier.

```
schedule(Ss, End) :-

    Ss = [S1,S2,S3],
    Es = [E1,E2,E3],


    Capacities = [
                 cumulative(12),  
                 cumulative(2),   
                 cumulative(10)   
    ],



    Tasks = [
            task(S1, 16, E1, [0,1,1], 1),    
            task(S2, 6, E2, [0,0,2], 2),    
            task(S3, 13, E3, [0,1,2], 3)    
    ],


    domain(Ss, 1, 30),
    maximum(End, Es),

    multi_cumulative(Tasks, Capacities),
    labeling([minimize(End)], Ss).
```

The problem is that, I need to have multiple resources. For example, I have the resources: "person_works_A" and "person_works_B". If I create a resource that can be a part of both (can work in both), how can I construct that? Because I don't have 1 resource "person_works_A" and another "person_works_B", I have 1 resource that can be both. When one is chosen, it's supposed to be left with 0 resources.

Thanks for the help